# std::set inserter not respecting custom comparator. (possible compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm finding that `std::inserter` on an `std::map<T, C>` does not always respect the custom comparator, but rather will sometimes fall back to the default `operator<`/`std::less`. Does anyone have any experience with why this may be? I feel like it could be a compiler bug, given the sporadic nature. In particular, I have a function like so:

```
template <typename T, typename C>
std::set<T, C> operator|(const std::set<T, C> &lhs, const std::set<T, C> &rhs)
{
  std::set<T, C> out;
  std::set_union(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
                 rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
                 inserter(out, out.end()));
  return out;
}
```

But this does not always use my custom `C` comparator, and sometimes (I know, I too wish I could find a pattern) will just use `std::less` instead. If I replace it with a maunal construction of the `std::insert_iterator<std::set<T, C>>`, everything works correctly:

```
template <typename T, typename C>
std::set<T, C> operator|(const std::set<T, C> &lhs, const std::set<T, C> &rhs)
{
  std::set<T, C> out;
  std::set_union(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
                 rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
                 std::insert_iterator<std::set<T, C>>(out, out.end()));
  return out;
}
```

I feel like this could be a compiler bug (gcc version 7.3.0) because the reference available on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter describes `inserter` to simply delegate to `insert_iterator`:

```
template< class Container >
std::insert_iterator<Container> inserter( Container& c, typename Container::iterator i )
{
    return std::insert_iterator<Container>(c, i);
}
```

Furthermore, the official C++ standard, section 24.5.2.5 (accessed via http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf, page 859) puts the definition of inserter as returning an insert iterator of the same type as is passed in the first argument:

```
template <class Container>
      insert_iterator<Container> inserter(Container& x, typename Container::iterator i);
```

Which clearly isn't happening here, as the returned `insert_iterator` is for a class of type `std::set<T, C = std::less<T>>`, not `std::set<T, C>`.

Is there an explanation for this besides compiler bug?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Ahhhhh, please do not override operators for STL types like this.

Comment: Pretend it just says `operatorOr` and let me go on wishing this was Python... ;)

Comment: Which version of the standard are you compiling against (this is important here)?

Comment: Please post a MCVE. If you have trouble with this due to the "sporadic" nature then describe your problem better at least. E.g. are you trying to say that the code randomly fails to compile? Does the same code compile again if you retry?  The description "the returned insert_iterator is for a class of type std::set<T, std::less<T>>" is not possible because such an iterator cannot refer to a `set<T, C>`. They are different types.

Comment: N3690 is a pre-C++14 draft. The latest standard is N4659

Comment: C++14. The code always compiles, but depending on the input will crash, as my current `operator<` does not define a weak partial ordering, and will sometimes throw an exception on particular unorderable pairs.

Comment: If it compiles then the returned `insert_iterator` is of the right type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"possible compiler bug" is to C++ what "It might be Lupus" is to House MD.

That being said, following the [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), you appear to be using version **1)** of the function, which clearly states:

> 1) Elements are compared using operator< and the ranges must be sorted with respect to the same.

What you should be doing, is pass your comparator to `std::set_union`, as per version **3)** of the function.

So the real mystery is: why is your comparator used at all sometimes. However, since you do not respect the preconditions of the function:

> the ranges must be sorted with respect to the same.

Then there is no expected behavior defined, so the behavior is not "incorrect".

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So in some sense the compiler bug would be when it did work, especially as my second version, where I construct a `std::insert_iterator<std::set<T, C>>` manually, does work, and certainly does not use `operator<`.

Comment: @Jackson, It's not really a compiler bug, in the sense that you are violating a precondition of the function ("ranges must be sorted with respect to the same."), so you are in no-mans land, and any possible resulting behavior is "correct". I've ammended the answer to explain it.